# Why won't pdb stop on breakpoints when using code in symlinked directories?

Tags: python, symlink, pdb

I am using Python-3.7.3. I have two files :

`tmp/add.py`

```
def add(a,b):
    print("hello")
    return(a+b)
```

`tmp/main.py`

```
from add import add
a=9
b=10
c=add(a,b)
```

If I run

```
$ python -m pdb tmp/main.py
> /home/user/tmp/main.py(1)<module>()
-> from add import add
(Pdb) b add.py : 2
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/tmp/add.py:2
(Pdb) c
> /home/user/tmp/add.py(2)add()
-> print("hello")
(Pdb)
```

`pdb` correctly stops on the breakpoint.  Now if I create a symlink to the directory (`ln -s tmp poo`) and try to run `pdb` on the symlinked directory:

```
$ python -m pdb poo/main.py
<function save_history at 0x2aaab21e1f28>
> /home/user/poo/main.py(1)<module>()
-> from add import add
(Pdb) b add.py : 2
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/tmp/add.py:2
(Pdb) c
hello
The program finished and will be restarted
```

Clearly, `pdb` failed to stop at the breakpoint and is having difficulties with the symlinks.

**Question**

Is there a way around this issue or am I just stuck going to the directory where my code lives and running `pdb` there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a solution to this is to type the full path to the file.

i.e.

```
from add import add
(Pdb) b /home/user/poo/add.py : 2
Breakpoint 1 at /home/user/poo/add.py:2
(Pdb) c
> /home/user/poo/add.py(2)add()
-> print("hello")
(Pdb)
```

It's still slightly stinky since it requires more key strokes.